# blow-up of a surface in a point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I've been reading Huybrecht's Complex Geometry, and ran across this question in section 2.5:

> Let $\hat X\rightarrow X$ be the blow-up of a surface $X$ in a point $x\in X$.Show that the pull-back of sections defines an isomorphism:
>   $$H^0(X,K_X)=H^0(\hat X,K_\hat X).$$

Does anyone have some ideas to solve this exercise?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hint: There's a maximal open set $U\subset X$ where the blowup is an isomorphism. Can you relate the behavior of top forms on $\hat{X}$ and $X$ via $U$?

Comment: @KReiser，Dear KReiser,thanks for your comment.On $U$,I think they can build an isomorphism relationship.However,I still can't figure it out.Suppose $\bigcup\left\{ U_j \right\}$ cover $X$, $x\in U_{j_0}$, $x\notin U_j$,where $j\ne j_0$.Then,in your statement,your $U=\bigcup\left\{ U_j|j\ne j_0 \right\}$,right?Can we use the proposition $$K_\hat X=\sigma ^*K_X\otimes\mathcal O_\hat X(E)$$,here $E=\sigma^{-1}(x)=\mathbb P^1$?Please provide more information,thanks.

Comment: Dear @KReiser,I think I can solve this problem,thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help - your answer shows you've found the correct maps but it's missing the interesting parts of the proof (showing that the maps are two-sided inverses to each other).

Comment: Dear @KReiser ,so sorry for my late reply.Yes,you are absolutely right,the proof need more addition.Now,if I can prove $H^0(\hat X\setminus E,K_{\hat X\setminus E})\cong H^0(\hat X,K_{\hat X})$,then all things all done,right? So our target is to show $H^0(E,K_E)=0$?I don't know whether my thoughts are right or not.Please feel free to point out my mistakes.Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would not proceed like that. Instead, I would use the maps: start with a section of $K_{\hat{X}}$, restrict to $U$, complete to a section of $K_{X}$, then pull it back. This doesn't change any of the values on $U$, so if it's not the same section you started with, then the difference is supported on the exceptional divisor. But this is impossible, since such a section would be torsion and no sections of a locally free sheaf on a smooth variety are torsion. ($K_{\hat{X}}$ is locally free since $\hat{X}$ is smooth).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write the solution here in case someone feel confused about the problem.

In fact, the problem can be generalized.$X$ can be a complex manifold of arbitrary dimension.For $dim=1$,the situation is trivial,since now,blowing-up along a point(divisor) does not change $X$,i.e.,$\hat X=X$.

For $dim\ge 2$,for one direction:$H^0(X,K_x)\rightarrow H^0(\hat X,K_\hat X)$,we make it possible by pulling up forms.For another direction,we first have restriction  $H^0(\hat X,K_\hat X)\rightarrow H^0(\hat X\setminus E,K_{\hat X\setminus E})$.In the same time,$H^0(\hat X\setminus E,K_{\hat X\setminus E})\cong H^0( X\setminus\left\{ x \right\},K_{X\setminus\left\{ x \right\}})$.Using Hartog's extension theorem,since $dim(X\setminus\left\{x\right\})\ge 2$,we have $H^0( X\setminus\left\{ x \right\},K_{X\setminus\left\{ x \right\}})=H^0(X,K_x)$.

We just need to show $H^0(\hat X,K_\hat X)=H^0(\hat X\setminus E,K_{\hat X\setminus E})$,since $$H^0(E,K_E)=H^0(E,\sigma ^* {K_X}\otimes\mathcal O(E)|_E),$$ $\sigma ^* {K_X}|E$ is trivial,$\mathcal O(E)|_E=\mathcal O(-1)$ has no global section.We get $H^0(E,K_E)=0$.

$Q.E.D.$